# ZF2 File upload validator always false

Tags: php, image, validation, file-upload, zend-framework2

In my form I have a file upload validator as the code below. The problem I am facing is that the adapter always send me a false on the validation. My question is what am I missing?

Below, code example and output;

```
# Set form data
$form->setValidationGroup('firstname', 'lastname');
$form->setData($request->getPost());

# Get file uploads
$file = $this->params()->fromFiles('avatar');

# Set image validators
$size      = new Size(array('min' => 0, 'max' => 1024000)); // 5kb / 500kb
$extension = new Extension(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'));
$adapter   = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
$adapter->setValidators(array($size, $extension), $file['name']);

Debug::dump($file);
Debug::dump($adapter->isValid());
Debug::dump($adapter->getMessages());
exit();


Output;

array(5) {
  ["name"] => string(10) "avatar.png"
  ["type"] => string(9) "image/png"
  ["tmp_name"] => string(14) "/tmp/phptkaBvc"
  ["error"] => int(0)
  ["size"] => int(171961)
}

bool(false)

array(1) {
  ["fileUploadErrorNoFile"] => string(24) "File '' was not uploaded"
}
```

Regards,
Nik

Answer (score 0):

```
$adapter->setDestination('/tmp');
```

Did the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

With ZF2 forms the correct method to upload files is to use the [File](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.elements.html#file) element on the form and a matching [FileInput](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.input-filter.file-input.html) on the InputFilter. The linked documentation pages show how to configure each.

Take note that you have to merge the POST and FILES data together and send that to `$form->setData`, as the InputFilter example shows. I failed to notice that the first time I built an upload form and it took embarrassingly much debugging to find the cause.